# How could we get the location of wifi tower by google geolocation service?

Tags: geolocation

Now, the location what is reported by google is related only to ip address of request but not related to wifi mac address.

You could check my statement with this:

```
torify curl -d '{version:"1.1.0",request_address:true,wifi_towers:[{mac_address:"00:00:00:00:00:00"}]}' www.google.com/loc/json
```

Answer (score 3):

```
www.google.com/loc/json
```

The Google Gears Geolocation API will stop responding to requests on November 17, 2012.
http://code.google.com/p/gears/wiki/GeolocationAPI

try

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/geolocation/#wifi_access_point_object

Answer (score -3):

try sniffing your android cellphone